# Getting rows for values greater by 3 numbers or letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

Am trying to come up with a query where I can return back values where the the distance between the letters could be one or more than one for the chosen letter.

For example:

I have two columns which have letters in **Column A** and in **Column B**. I want to return back with rows when **column B** distance is more than **Column A** by one or more letters.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What about case sensitivity? Is 'd' two greater than 'B'? Add more sample data, somewhat tricky, and also specify the expected result.

Comment: am using MS SQL. Case sensitivity is all are UPPERCASE

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me, when you say "greater" if you mean that the distance between any two letters is 2 or 3 (Column B can be alphabetically before or after Column A, by a distance of 2 or 3).. Or if Column B has to be alphabetically after Column A, by a distance of 2 or 3

Because I'm not certain what you're talking about, I present two options. Read the "if" rule and choose the one that applies to your situation, then use the query under it:

- If columnA is `D` and columnB can be any of: `A B F G`

  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ABS(ASCII(columna) - ASCII(columnb)) IN (2,3)`
- If columnA is `D` and columnB can be any of: `F G`

  `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ASCII(columnb) - ASCII(columna) IN (2,3)`

**Edit1:** Per your later comment, you are now saying that the distance is not just 2 or 3 letters (the first line of your question states "2 or 3") but any number of letters distance equal to or greater than 2:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ASCII(columnb) - ASCII(columna) >= 2
```

Overall the technique isn't much different to the above queries and there are many ways to specify what you want:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE 
  ASCII(columnb) - ASCII(columna) 
  BETWEEN <some_number_here> AND <other_number_here>
```

Ultimately the most important thing is to note the use of ASCII function, which gives us the ascii char code of the first letter in a string:

```
ASCII('ABCD') => 65
```

And we can use maths on this to work out if a letter distance from 'A' is more than 1 etc..

Probably also worth noting that `ASCII()` works on single byte ascii characters. If your data is multibyte (Unicode), you might need to use `ORD()` instead:

**Edit2:** Your latest edit to the question revises the limit to "B greater than A by one or more" which is equivalent to `>= 1` ..

The question seems not to have a clear spec, please treat the answer as a guide for the general technique:

```
--for an open ended distance, ascii chars
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ASCII(columnb) - ASCII(columna) >= <some_distance>

--for an open ended distance, unicode
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ORD(columnb) - ORD(columna) >= <some_distance>

--for a definite range of distances (replace … appropriately)
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE ... BETWEEN <some_distance> AND <some_other_distance>
```

Comment: the user is askig for exact two places greater and col1 ia lesser than col2

Comment: Whats ABS being used for?

Comment: @nikhilsugandh you are only interpreting the question one way, but I personally don't find the wording to be precise enough to be certain. Regardless of whether you agree or not, the point you seem to be making is answered by the second query

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses yall are amazing. This is my first time in stack overflow

Comment: What i mean is by distance. In both columns i have many letters. So i want to match both columns only if the distance is more by 2 letters. So if columnA is D then it should return rows only if the distance is by 2 letters which means it will return back rows if letters in columnB are G or further than G

Answer (score 0):

this will work indeed:

```
select * from table_name where ascii(col_1)+2=ascii(col_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this if you need it to be exactly 2 or 3 letters greater

select Column A, ColumnB from table name where ASCII(ColumnB) - ASCII(ColumnA) in (2,3)

If you want all those rows where the the difference is equal more than 2, then use this

select Column A, ColumnB from table name where ASCII(ColumnB) - ASCII(ColumnA) >=2

Comment: I dont need it to be exactly. It could go further

Comment: Then you can use the 2nd query

Answer (score 0):

this is where you can make **ascii** in action..

```
select * from SampleTable where (ASCII(sampleTable.ColumnB) - ASCII(ColumnA)) >= 2;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that your answer is posted later, but it doesn't add anything new over and above the other answers on the page. Please avoid posting answers that are duplicates of other answers